# SOAP Webservice returns wrong date sometimes

Tags: web-services, date, soap

I have developed one soap webservice long ago (4 years back) in Java Spring. It takes one date parameter and returns error message if that date is future date (greater than today's date), otherwise it updates that date into DB.

Till now this webservice worked fine everytime, but sometimes (once in 50 calls) it returns wrong/malicious future date.

Please find some of the failed examples below -

```
 Input Date -  20161215
 Error Message -  Thu Dec 15 00:00:00 EET 20162016 (future dates not allowed) 

 Input Date -  20161226
 Error Message -  Tue Sep 26 00:00:00 EEST 20162017 (future dates not allowed) 

 Input Date -  20150604
 Error Message -  Sat Feb 01 00:00:00 EET 20152020 (future dates not allowed) 

 Input Date -  20150630
 Error Message -  Tue Jun 30 00:00:00 EEST 20152015 (future dates not allowed) 

 Input Date -  20150706
 Error Message -  Sun Dec 06 00:00:00 EET 2020 (future dates not allowed) 

 Input Date -  20161201
 Error Message -  Wed Feb 08 00:00:00 EET 2017 (future dates not allowed) 

 Input Date -  20161206
 Error Message -  Tue Dec 06 00:00:00 EET 6016 (future dates not allowed) 

 Input Date -  20161001
 Error Message -  Mon Apr 29 00:00:00 EEST 2024 (future dates not allowed)
```

If it is code error, I should get errors for every hit, but I'm not.
This webservice get concurrent hits, may be that causes this error?

Please provide your comments..

Comment: Please, show your code and the XSD mapping

Comment: Tip: The modern [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes that supplant the old legacy date-time classes use [immutable objects](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) and so are inherently [thread-safe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). Use the java.time classes to avoid [concurrency](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)) failures.